# I can't view .xaml files in the solutions explorer in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just Added Content Page (.xaml) but I can't view the file created, just a .xaml.cs file.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017

Answer (score 1):

Open the file named yourProjectName.projitems

In that add following code

```
<ItemGroup>    
  <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Views\YourPageName.xaml.cs">
    <DependentUpon>YourPageName.xaml</DependentUpon>
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource 
      Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Views\YourPageName.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you need a **ContentPage with XAML** you should select `Froms ContentsPage Xaml` instead of `Forms ContentPage`